# Watch for file creation > Pick the file name > add it after script and run

Tags: bash, unix

I need to create bash script that will pick file name, add it to command and run it.
What I want to do is to look in /home/ctl/ for *.ctl files creation, once there is a file created, for example 13.21.23.ctl, to pick its name and run another script with the name behind the script, for example ./tools/script.sh 13.21.23

Can you please advise if we can do this with the default tools for RedHat ?

Sorry for the lame question, new to bash :/
Thanks in advance !

Best regards,
Alex

Comment: On linux, you can use inotifywait from the inotify-tools package.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like this (note that this is **not tested** since I have no access to inotifywait)

```
inotifywait -m /home/ctl -e create -e moved_to |
    while read directory action file
    do
        if [[ "$file" =~ .ctl$  ]]
        then
            ./tools/script.sh "${file%.*}"
        fi
    done
```

On Ubuntu, `inotifywait` is in the package `inotify-tools`